# For which built-in C++ type is the law of excluded middle violated?

Tags: c++, programming-logic, logic

Apparently, for some built-in type of C++, the following does not hold: `a==b || a!=b`
Which type/value is it?

The question is originally from

this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etZgaSjzqlU&index=4&list=PLHxtyCq_WDLV5N5zUCBCDC2WqF1VBDGg1 at the beginning,

for which the slides are:

http://stepanovpapers.com/Journeys/Journey1.pdf problem 70.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is... there is no answer.

C++, like C, does not require particular representations for its arithmetic types. Unsigned integers are required to follow binary arithmetic for some number of bits. But beyond that, little is specified.

Arithmetic types are permitted (but not required) to have so-called "trap representations". These are bit-patterns that represent an erroneous condition. These would violate the "excluded middle" rule, as trap values usually are not considered equal to other trap values, even if they're the same bit-pattern.

But C++ does not specify that any particular type will have trap representations. You can check if a particular arithmetic type traps with `std::numeric_limits<T>::traps`. But this is an implementation-specific limitation, not a standard defined construct.

Comment: This is a good answer, except for the IEEE-754 example, which does *not* exhibit the behavior the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't hold for any uninitialised variable with a built-in type. Both a == b and a != b invoke undefined behaviour if a or b are uninitialised. "Undefined behaviour" includes the possibility that both compare equal or both compare unequal (and of course all other possible consequences).

The IEEE 754 behaviour is actually different. It states that if one number is NaN, then both numbers compare unequal. Even when they are the same. And (+0) and (-0) compare equal, even though they are not the same. **But (a == b) || (a != b) remains true**. What isn't true for NaNs is (a < b) || (a == b) || (a > b). All three are false for NaNs.

Comment: Also worth noting that the idea that undefined behaviour might cause comparison inconsistencies is not idle speculation... This does happen with real optimizing compilers today - they may well be aware that one of your variables is uninitialized and optimize away any comparisons with it, just returning false whatever you compare it against.

Comment: I wrote about this elsewhere, but I'll repeat a condensed version here: modern optimizing compilers are essentially theorem provers: they try to prove that certain conditions hold, under which certain optimizations are legal. Invoking UB allows the compiler to assume *anything*, which means that it can prove *any* condition it wants and thus apply *any* optimization. This means that in modern optimizing compilers, UB can lead to much more "surprising" behavior than in the past. E.g. reading from uninitialized memory would in the past mean that you read garbage. Today, it can mean *anything*.

Answer (score 0):

I tested NaN, and a==b || a!=b is true.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
int main(){
        double a = NAN;
        double b = 45.3; // NAN here has same result
        if( (a==b) || (a!=b) ) std::cout << "true\n";
        else std::cout << "false\n";
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check if your [compiler option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) contains `-ffinite-math-only`.